# Cannot find a short story named something like "Mask of the Silver King"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the mid nineties I received a short story anthology as a gift.  I believe it was either a Weird Tales anthology, or White Wolf.  My favorite story was called *Mask of the Silver King*, (I think, I may be a little off.)

It was a fantasy story about a child and his older brother coming of age.  The child's older brother becomes a criminal, and the younger child becomes a musician (I think) and somehow rises to power and becomes a god like creature known as the Silver King.  I cannot find the story for the life of me, and I am hoping that someone here may be able to help.

The only other detail that I can remember is that (I think) Tanith Lee's "[The Sombrus Tower](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77381)" was in the same anthology.

Any help at all is appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?288435) (or another binding) is the *Weird Tales* anthology. There's no story with a similar title there, but maybe one of the titles rings a bell? *[Mysteries of the Faceless King](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?835657)*, perhaps?

Comment: @Gilles 9 of 14 pages from Mysteries of the Faceless King are available [on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=4OO_Kn5a6JoC&lpg=PA2&dq=%22weird%20tales%20290%22&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @rintaun Thanks! For some reason Weird Tales 290 doesn't turn up when I search for “faceless king”, only Weird Tales 291. It's definitely a match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking up [“The Sombrus Tower”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77381) on [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/) shows that it was published in *Weird Tales* in 1980 and collected in a [*Weird Tales* anthology](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?288435). The closest match for a title in this anthology is [“The Mysteries of the Faceless King”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77344) by [Darrell Schweitzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darrell_Schweitzer). The [extract readable on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=4OO_Kn5a6JoC&lpg=PA2&dq=%22weird%20tales%20290%22&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q&f=false) shows that it's a good match for what you remember.

Comment: Thank you! The Mysteries of the Faceless King is the story I was looking for. I have been looking for this story off and on for years, thank a million.